# Is my NTP configuration working (with a multicast peer)?

Tags: ntp, multicast

## Introduction

I'm trying to do some work in which I must receive an NTP update from peers but I'm concerned that there isn't any being received. Here's the output of `ntpq -np`:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset jitter  
==========================================================================
     239.0.1.1       .MCST.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

Does the fact that the `reach`, `delay`, `offset` are all zeroes means that this host hasn't received any information from peers?

## Details

I've also done `ntpq`, with command `associations` and received the following:

```
ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 12097  c811   yes  none   yes    reject    mobilize  1
```

Here's my `ntp.conf`:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1

statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/
logfile /var/log/ntpstats/ntpd.log

tos orphan 4
broadcast 239.0.1.1 key 1 ttl 1        # multicast server
multicastclient 239.0.1.1              # multicast client

keys /etc/ntp/keys
trustedkey 1
```

Here's the output log at `/var/log/ntpstats/ntpd.log`:

```
 2 Jan 16:19:57 ntpd[3554]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
 2 Jan 16:19:57 ntpd[3554]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
 2 Jan 16:19:57 ntpd[3554]: Listen normally on 1 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
 2 Jan 16:19:57 ntpd[3554]: Listen normally on 2 eth0.10 10.3.1.2 UDP 123
 2 Jan 16:19:57 ntpd[3554]: Listen normally on 3 eth0.172 172.20.20.2 UDP 123
 2 Jan 16:19:57 ntpd[3554]: Listening on routing socket on fd #20 for interface updates
 2 Jan 16:19:57 ntpd[3554]: Listen normally on 4 multicast 239.0.1.1 UDP 123
 2 Jan 16:19:57 ntpd[3554]: Joined 239.0.1.1 socket to multicast group 239.0.1.1
 2 Jan 16:19:57 ntpd[3554]: 0.0.0.0 c016 06 restart
 2 Jan 16:19:57 ntpd[3554]: 0.0.0.0 c012 02 freq_set kernel 0.000 PPM
 2 Jan 16:19:57 ntpd[3554]: 0.0.0.0 c011 01 freq_not_set
 2 Jan 16:19:58 ntpd[3554]: io_setbclient: Opened broadcast client on interface #3 eth0.172
 2 Jan 16:19:58 ntpd[3554]: io_setbclient: Opened broadcast client on interface #2 eth0.10
 2 Jan 16:30:35 ntpd[3554]: 0.0.0.0 0614 04 freq_mode
```

## Questions

#### Question 1

***Is my NTP configuration receiving updates? If not, how can it be fixed?***

#### Question 2 (Supplemental/Optional)

From what I understand, a multicast peer indicates that any host in the multicast group can send and receive NTP information from any other host, is this accurate?

#### Question 3 (Supplemental/Optional)

What do the last 6 lines of the log indicate (alternatively, where can I find documentation which explains)? Of particular interest to me is the following:

```
0.0.0.0 c012 02 freq_set kernel 0.000 PPM
```

I don't really understand any part of this. Does `0.0.0.0` indicate some peer behind the multicast address? What does `c012` and `02` mean? Isn't this setting the drift time (the clock drifts 0 seconds over 0 seconds)?

Comment: You may also want to include ntp.conf. I don't know anything about multicast NTP, unfortunately.

Comment: @Karobar Obvious question - is multicast *enabled* on the network switches & routers? - your output says no its not working...